# Is the function $f(x)=\int_0^\pi \ln |x+\cos(t)| dt$ differentible in interval (-1, 1)？

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives, definite-integrals

[image]
I tried to garph the function $f(x)=\int_0^\pi \ln |x+\cos(t)| dt$ and $f'(x)$ in desmos as above. Even $f(x)$ behaves like a constant function in $(-1,1)$ , but it seems not differentible in $(-1,1)$. Why? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Neither desmos or Wolfram Alpha (or others) have a brain. Those are just tools. Computer programs with algorithms to do some calculations. It's very easy to find problems that fall out of its capabilities. Since we often don't have access to the details of its programming, we have to use them always using our own brain, to check for any strange result.

Comment: For $x\in (0,1)$, we have $f(x)=\int_0^\pi \ln(x+\cos(t))dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absence of the part of the derivative of the function on $(-1, 1)$ is probably just an artifact of how Desmos evaluates functions specified in terms of integrals. Saying much more would require knowing how Desmos implements that functionality.

In any case, it's not so bad to compute the integral explicitly and hence check where it's differentiable. [Differentiating under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) gives:
$$\int_0^\pi \log |x + \cos t| \,dt =
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\pi(\operatorname{arcosh} |x| -     \log 2) , \quad |x| \geq 1 \\
                              - \pi \log 2  , \quad |x| \leq 1
\end{array}
\right. .
$$
In particular, the function is differentiable everywhere except at $\pm 1$.

Comment: Okay, I see. I'm appriciate for your useful help .